# Find measure of an open interval given closed interval

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu([0, a])=e^a, a\ge 0$. Find $\int (1_{(0,2)}+21_{[1,3]})d\mu$.

I've run into some trouble finding $\mu((0, 2))$. I know that $\mu((0, 2))+\mu(\{0\})+\mu(\{2\})=\mu([0,2])=e^2$ and that $\mu(\{0\})=e^0=1$. But there are two unknowns in the equation.

Just as for $e^3=\mu([0, 3])=\mu([0,1))+\mu([1, 3])$, I don't know what $\mu([0, 1))$ is so I can't solve for $\mu([1, 3])$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$
\mu((a,b])=\mu([0,b]\setminus [0,a])=e^b-e^a
$$
for $0\leq a<b$.

Moreover,
$$
\mu(a,b)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(a,b-1/n]\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(a,b-1/n)=e^b-e^a.
$$

In particular, the measure $\mu$ has no atoms. I think you can take it from here.